# BeautifulSoup remove everything after variable

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I have a html with multiple elements of the same kind. I need to remove everything after the last element of its kind.

```
html = '''
<p>Some text element.</p>
<p>Some other text element.</p>
<p class="myclass">This is an element with class</p>
<p>This is an element without class.</p>
<p>Other paragraph.</p>
<p class="myclass">The second element with class.</p>
<p>Another paragraph.</p>
<p>More</p>
<p>...</p>
'''
```

And I manage to select the last element of class, but I have no idea how to select everything after my variable. Found no informations about removing regexed variable.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
# Selecting all elements with class
ps_with_class = soup.find_all('p',{'class':'myclass'}
# if elements exist
if ps_with_class:
    # Selecting last element
    last_p_with_class = ps_with_class[-1]
    # How to remove something like r"last_p_with_class*" from html? maybe using /import re/
```

If I can remove everything after the second element with class "myclass", the output should then be:

```
<p>Some text element.</p>
<p>Some other text element.</p>
<p class="myclass">This is an element with class</p>
<p>This is an element without class.</p>
<p>Other paragraph.</p>
<p class="myclass">The second element with class.</p>
```

Comment: `html.rsplit('<p class="myclass">', 1)[0]`

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to also show your expected output for your example?

Comment: thank you @RJAdriaansen, I could split, but I don't want to. I needed to know if I can remove everything after the last element with class using Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a combination of `.next_sibling` and `extract()` to remove all elements following the second matching `<p>`.

For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

html = '''
<p>Some text element.</p>
<p>Some other text element.</p>
<p class="myclass">This is an element with class</p>
<p>This is an element without class.</p>
<p>Other paragraph.</p>
<p class="myclass">The second element with class.</p>
<p>Another paragraph.</p>
<p>More</p>
<p>...</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
second = soup.find_all('p', {'class':'myclass'})[1]
sibling = second.next_sibling

while sibling:
    next_sibling = sibling.next_sibling
    sibling.extract()
    sibling = next_sibling
    
print(soup)
```

This would produce an updated HTML as:

```
<html><body><p>Some text element.</p>
<p>Some other text element.</p>
<p class="myclass">This is an element with class</p>
<p>This is an element without class.</p>
<p>Other paragraph.</p>
<p class="myclass">The second element with class.</p></body></html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Regex is not possible?

Comment: Not reliably, If possible try and avoid using regex to parse HTML, I would not recommend it